# How to decrease number of database rows used by MediaWiki?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, mediawiki

I've installed MediaWiki (with two langs used: ru and en) on free Heroku instance with PostgreSQL usage. Now Heroku says me that my database contains 10252 row (which is above 10000 rows allowed). I've installed PostgreSQL Studio addon, looks like 9756 rows used by `l10n_cache` table. Is there anything I can do to decrease this number?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [`$wgCacheDirectory`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCacheDirectory).

Comment: Thanks! Can I just delete the existing table `l10n_cache`? Also, I defined `$wgCacheDirectory` as `"$wgScriptPath/cache"`, but it doesn't work - I get `Fatal exception of type MWException`.

Comment: Looks like usage of `$wgScriptPath` was the reason of the problem. Finally (after playing with folder rights, names etc.) I've defined the value of `$wgCacheDirectory` as `"cache/"` and it started to work. Btw, dropping of `l10n_cache` with `db` cache used was leading to the DB problems, but once  `$wgCacheDirectory` works, `l10n_cache` could be safely dropped.